# Paypal IPN listener not sending mysql insert statement

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, listener, paypal-ipn

I got a paypal ipn code from somewhere. Cant remember where but it works with the ipn simulator when you delete the date from the date field. It does not work with the date. I am now testing with a live payment and it sends the ipn successfully from paypal and no error log. The HTTP response is 200 but nothing is inserted into my database.

Any ideas why it is not working?

Here is the code:

```
<?php
class PayPal_IPN{
function infotuts_ipn($im_debut_ipn) {

define('SSL_P_URL', 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
 define('SSL_SAND_URL', 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
 $hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
 if (!preg_match('/paypal\.com$/', $hostname)) {
 $ipn_status = 'Validation post isn\'t from PayPal';
 if ($im_debut_ipn == true) {
 // mail test
 }

return false;
 }

// parse the paypal URL
 $paypal_url = ($_REQUEST['test_ipn'] == 1) ? SSL_SAND_URL : SSL_P_URL;
 $url_parsed = parse_url($paypal_url);

 $post_string = '';
 foreach ($_REQUEST as $field => $value) {
 $post_string .= $field . '=' . urlencode(stripslashes($value)) . '&';
 }
 $post_string.="cmd=_notify-validate"; // append ipn command
 // get the correct paypal url to post request to
 $paypal_mode_status = $im_debut_ipn; //get_option('im_sabdbox_mode');
 if ($paypal_mode_status == true)
 $fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', "443", $err_num, $err_str, 60);
 else
 $fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.paypal.com', "443", $err_num, $err_str, 60);

$ipn_response = '';

if (!$fp) {
// could not open the connection. If loggin is on, the error message
// will be in the log.
 $ipn_status = "fsockopen error no. $err_num: $err_str";
 if ($im_debut_ipn == true) {
 echo 'fsockopen fail';
 }
 return false;
 } else {
// Post the data back to paypal
 fputs($fp, "POST $url_parsed[path] HTTP/1.1\r\n");
 fputs($fp, "Host: $url_parsed[host]\r\n");
 fputs($fp, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
 fputs($fp, "Content-length: " . strlen($post_string) . "\r\n");
 fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
 fputs($fp, $post_string . "\r\n\r\n");

// loop through the response from the server and append to variable
 while (!feof($fp)) {
 $ipn_response .= fgets($fp, 1024);
 }
 fclose($fp); // close connection
 }

// Invalid IPN transaction. Check the $ipn_status and log for details.
 if (!preg_match("/VERIFIED/s", $ipn_response)) {
 $ipn_status = 'IPN Validation Failed';

if ($im_debut_ipn == true) {
 echo 'Validation fail';
 print_r($_REQUEST);
 }
 return false;
 } else {
 $ipn_status = "IPN VERIFIED";
 if ($im_debut_ipn == true) {
 echo 'SUCCESS';

 }

return true;
 }
 }
 function ipn_response($request){
 mail("info@vertexskysports.com","Order Recieved",print_r($request,true));
 $im_debut_ipn=true;
 if ($this->infotuts_ipn($im_debut_ipn)) {

 // if paypal sends a response code back let's handle it
 if ($im_debut_ipn == true) {
 $sub = 'PayPal IPN Debug Email Main';
 $msg = print_r($request, true);
 $aname = 'infotuts';
 //mail send
 }

// process the membership since paypal gave us a valid +
 $this->insert_data($request);
 }
 }
function issetCheck($post,$key){
if(isset($post[$key])){
$return=$post[$key];
}
else{
$return='';
}
return $return;
}
 function insert_data($request){




$con=mysql_connect("xxx.xxx.xx.xx","USERNAME","PASSWORD") or die("Failed to connect with database!!!!");
mysql_select_db("DATABASENAME", $con); 


$datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$order_number = $_POST['custom'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$payer_id = $_POST['payer_id'];
$payer_status = $_POST['payer_status'];
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$address_city = $_POST['address_city'];
$address_country = $_POST['address_country'];
$address_state = $_POST['address_state'];
$address_status = $_POST['address_status'];
$address_country_code = $_POST['address_country_code'];
$address_name = $_POST['address_name'];
$address_street = $_POST['address_street'];
$address_zip = $_POST['address_zip'];
$item_name = $_POST['item_name1'];
$fee = $_POST['mc_fee'];
$amount = $_POST['mc_gross_1'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$shipping = $_POST['mc_shipping'];


$design = "INSERT INTO orders(datetime, order_number, receiver_email, txn_id, payer_email, payer_id, payer_status, first_name, last_name, address_city, address_country, address_state, address_country_code, address_name, address_street, address_zip, item_name, fee, amount, payment_status, shipping)
VALUES('".$datetime."', '".$order_number."', '".$receiver_email."', '".$txn_id."', '".$payer_email."', '".$payer_id."', '".$payer_status."', '".$first_name."', '".$last_name."', '".$address_city."', '".$address_country."', '".$address_state."', '".$address_country_code."', '".$address_name."', '".$address_street."', '".$address_zip."', '".$item_name."', '".$fee."', '".$amount."', '".$payment_status."', '".$shipping."')";

mysql_query($design);

$design2 = "INSERT INTO order_status(datetime, order_number, status) VALUES('".$datetime."','".$order_number."','Received')";

mysql_query($design2);


 }
 }
 $obj = New PayPal_IPN();
 $obj->ipn_response($_REQUEST);

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to test that sort of thing is to setup your own simulator so you can run it in a browser and see the result on screen.  This will help you troubleshoot any potential SQL insert problems, missing data, or whatever might be causing the problem.

So just setup an HTML form with hidden fields matching the fields you expect to get from IPN.  Submit that directly to your listener in a browser.

Of course, make sure to handle the fact that the data isn't coming from PayPal, so it won't verify, but you can setup logic to handle that accordingly.

More details are available in this article I wrote about [how to test PayPal IPN](https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/).